# Find the first derivative $y=\sqrt\frac{1+\cosθ}{1-\cosθ}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

$$y=\sqrt\frac{1+\cosθ}{1-\cosθ}$$ my professor said that the answer is $$y'=\frac{1}{\cosθ-1}$$ she said use half angle formula but I just end up with $\frac{(-2\sinθ)\sqrt{(1-\cosθ)(1+\cosθ)}}{2(1-\cosθ)^2(1+\cosθ)}$ I used the quotient rule. I also know that ${(1-\cosθ)^2}$ can be $\sinθ^2$ but i try to apply my identities but it's still wrong.

Comment: $1-\cos^2 \theta=\sin \theta$ and NOT $(1-\cos \theta)^2=\sin ^2 \theta$. Please see that.

Comment: @Abstraction You made a typo ;-)

Comment: @Mickey Is there any restriction on the domain of $\theta$?

Comment: Your professor is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

$$y=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\theta}{1-\cos\theta}}=\sqrt{\frac{2\cos^2\theta/2}{2\sin^2\theta/2}}=|\cot\theta/2|$$

Also,

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\cot(\theta/2)=-\frac12\frac1{\sin^2\theta/2}$$

Hence, when $\cos\theta/2\neq0$ and $\sin\theta/2\neq 0$, that is when $\theta\notin\pi\Bbb Z$,

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}\theta}=-\frac12\frac{\mathrm{sign}(\cot \theta/2)}{\sin^2\theta/2}$$

And since $2\sin^2\theta/2=1-\cos\theta$,

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}\theta}=-\frac{\mathrm{sign}(\cot \theta/2)}{1-\cos\theta}$$

And yet one more simplification, when $\sin\theta/2\neq 0$,

$$\mathrm{sign}(\cot \theta/2)=\mathrm{sign}(\cos (\theta/2)\sin (\theta/2))=\mathrm{sign}(\sin\theta)$$

So, still for $\theta\notin\pi\Bbb Z$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}\theta}=-\frac{\mathrm{sign}(\sin\theta)}{1-\cos\theta}$$

Since it may not be absolutely clear, here is a plot of $y$, to show how $y$ differs from $\cot\theta/2$. Notice the angle when the curve reaches $0$: $y$ is thus not differentiable here.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We have

$\dfrac{(-2\sinθ)\sqrt{(1-\cosθ)(1+\cosθ)}}{2(1-\cosθ)^2(1+\cosθ)}=-\dfrac{2\sin\theta|\sin\theta|}{2(1-\cos\theta)(1-\cos^2\theta)}$

=-sign$(\sin\theta)\dfrac1{1-\cos\theta}$

Comment: can you expand the solution please, Did you use the quotient rule?

Comment: @Mickey, I've started  where you left of

Comment: @Mickey, $$(1-\cosθ)(1+\cosθ)=\sin^2\theta$$  $$\implies\sqrt{(1-\cosθ)(1+\cosθ)}=|\sin\theta|$$

Comment: I got the numerator but how did you get rid of the denominator $(1+cosθ)$ ?

Comment: @Mickey, $$(1-\cos\theta)^2(1+\cos\theta)=(1-\cos\theta)(1-\cos\theta)(1+\cos\theta)$$  $$=(1-\cos\theta)(1-\cos^2\theta)=(1-\cos\theta)\sin^2\theta$$

Comment: thank you so much! my professor just laughs at our answers and lets us think the answer forever. thank thank thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17284/discussion-between-mickey-and-lab-bhattacharjee).

Comment: @Mickey But your teacher is wrong if he forgets $sign(sin(\theta))$

Comment: @jean i think it will all cancel? since $\frac{-2sin^2θ}{-2sin^2θ(cosθ-1)}$ since she factored out the negative in the denominator?

Comment: @Mickey In numerator, it's NOT $\sin^2\theta$, it's $\sin\theta|\sin\theta|=\mathrm{sign}(\sin \theta)\sin^2\theta$. Absolutely not the same thing.

Comment: @jean I have a question so the answer is supposed to be $-|sinθ|\frac{1}{sinθ(1-cosθ)}$ right? since if its not a squared numerator then i'm left with another sinθ in the denominator?

Comment: @lab i just realized it now so where is the sinθ denominator? if the numerator is not $sin^2θ$?

Comment: @Mickey when $x\neq 0$, $sign(x)=|x|/x$, so it's $+1$ or $-1$ according to sign of $x$, and $sign(0)=0$. However, you have to pay attention to the domain of definition of your derivative: absolute value is not differentiable at $0$, and neither is $sign$. And on intervals where $\sin\theta$ keeps the same sign, $sign(\sin \theta)$ is simply a constant, so you can factor it when you differentiate (but it's still here afterwards of course)

Comment: @Mickey Hence, basically, the derivative of $sign(g(x))f(x)$ is simply $sign(g(x)) f'(x)$, except that the derivative does not exist (in general) when $g(x)=0$. It exists only if, for such $x$, you have also $f(x)=0$ and the product is differentiable (you would have to check, but here it's not a problem). For instance, $sign(x)|x|=x$ is of course differentiable at $0$, but $sign(x)x=|x|$ is not.

Answer (score 2):

The half angle formulas are often useful:
$$\cos^2(x)=\dfrac{1+\cos(2x)}{2} \text{ and } \sin^2(x)=\dfrac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$$

$$y=\sqrt{\dfrac{(1+\cos\theta)/2}{(1-\cos\theta)/2}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{\cos^2(\theta/2)}{\sin^2(\theta/2)}}=\sqrt{\cot^2(\theta/2)}=\left|\cot(\theta/2)\right|$$

The derivative of $\cot(x)$ is $(\cot(x))'=-(1+\cot^2(x))=\dfrac{-1}{\sin^2x}$

Comment: I think $y'= -csc(x)^2$ of $cot(x)$ ? so it's $-1/sin2x$ right? anyway got the answer from lab thank you too! gonna try this out with the other problems

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{1+\cos\theta}{1-\cos\theta}=\dfrac{(1+\cos\theta)(1-\cos\theta)}{(1-\cos\theta)^2}=\left(\dfrac{\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta}\right)^2$

So,$\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos\theta}{1-\cos\theta}}=$sign of $(\sin\theta)\cdot\dfrac{\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta}$

Now apply quotient Rule

Comment: @Mickey, Here is another method

Answer (score 1):

$$ y^2=\frac {1+\cos\theta}{1-\cos\theta}.$$

Differentiating gives

$$\frac {d}{d\theta} y^2=\frac {d}{d\theta} \frac {1+\cos\theta}{1-\cos\theta} = -\frac{2\sin\theta}{(1-\cos\theta)^2}. $$

Using the chain rule gives for the left hand side

$$2y\frac {dy}{d\theta}. $$ Hence, $$\frac {dy}{d\theta}=-\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos\theta}}{\sqrt{1+\cos\theta}}\frac{\sin\theta}{(1-\cos\theta)^2},$$ a plot of which agrees with that of Jean-Claude Arbaut's answer.

Assuming this to be the case then retrospectively it would seem that

$$\text{sgn}(\sin\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{1-\cos\theta}}{\sqrt{1+\cos\theta}}\frac{\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta}.$$

Interesting.

---

Out of curiosity, let $\theta= \arcsin x$. Then

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos\theta}}{\sqrt{1+\cos\theta}}\frac{\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}} \sqrt{\sqrt{1-x^2}+1}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\frac{x}{\mid x\mid}=\text{sgn}(x) .$$

Answer (score 0):

Using half angle formula $$\cos\theta =2\cos^2(\theta/2)-1$$ and $$\cos\theta =1-2\sin^2(\theta/2).$$

So,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
y & = \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\theta}{1-\cos\theta}}\\
& = \sqrt{\frac{2\cos^2(\theta/2)}{2\sin^2(\theta/2)}}\\
& = \frac{\cos(\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)} \quad \text{ for } 0^{\circ}\le \frac{\theta}{2}\le 90^\circ
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Now, by using quotient rule $y'=\frac{-1/2}{\sin^2(\theta /2)}$, using half angle formula again we have $$y'=\frac{-1}{1-\cos\theta}.$$

---

Your professor's answer is correct provided that the denominator is $1-\cos\theta$ not $\cos\theta -1.$

Comment: No, it's wrong. $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, not $x$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut what can you say about $(-x)^2=x^2$? What we have under that square root is positive, whatever the value of   $\cos(\theta/2)$.

Comment: You write the square root equals
$$\frac{\cos\theta/2}{\sin\theta/2}$$
Which is of course not always positive. How can a square root be negative, exactly?

I repeat,
$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$$
And $|x|\neq x$ when $x<0$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut can you explain the down vote?

Comment: I just explained. You are writing that $y=\cot \theta/2$, though $y$ is always positive or zero, by definition.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I know that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, can you provide a counterexample that shows $\frac{\cos(\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)}$ is negative?

Comment: Sure, $\theta=-\pi/2$, $\cot (-\pi/4)=-1$. See the plot I provided above.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I have restricted the domain of my answer.

Comment: Still wrong. You add the restriction $0<\theta/2<\pi$, but if $\pi/2<\theta/2<\pi$, then $\cos\theta/2<0$ and $\sin\theta/2>0$, so $\cot\theta/2<0$. By the way, you are not supposed to add a restriction on $\theta$ (not in the statement of the question).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Suppose to be $0<\theta /2<\pi /2$. What of if the question does not provide all the information needed to solve the problem?

Comment: You have all the information needed. Now, either you restrict the interval so that you don't need an absolute value (what you did), either you make as few assumptions as possible, and you use absolute value, that is $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, and you differentiate carefully. But, bear in mind that no restriction on $\theta$ is *necessary*, it's an artificial limitation of the answer to make it simpler, or to hide the fact that $\sqrt{x^2}$ is not really $x$ in general. But you are right in asking the OP if there was a limitation in the first place :-)